# Python logging: use milliseconds in time format

Tags: python, logging, time, python-logging

By default `logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s')` prints with the following format:

```
2011-06-09 10:54:40,638
```

where 638 is the millisecond. I need to change the comma to a dot:

```
2011-06-09 10:54:40.638
```

To format the time I can use:

```
logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s',datestr=date_format_str)
```

however the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) doesn't specify how to format milliseconds. I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python) which talks about microseconds, but a) I would prefer milliseconds and b) the following doesn't work on Python 2.6 (which I'm working on) due to the `%f`:

```
logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Maybe changing the locale could help?

Comment: @ pajton - in the following link it says "Locale information is not used by asctime()" - http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.asctime

Comment: `%f` doesn't work on python 2.7.9 or 3.5.1 either

Comment: Good conversation here. I came here because `logging` claims its default time format follows ISO 8601. It doesn't. It uses space, not "T" to separate time and comma for fractional seconds, not decimal point. How could they be so wrong?

Answer (score 530, accepted):

This should work too:

```
logging.Formatter(
    fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S'
)
```

Comment: Thanks: Here are the docs for these: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes .. Is there a way to still include the timezone (%z)? ... ISO8601 format times in Python logs (, -> .) would be great.

Comment: This solution is handicapped, because if you have `%z` or `%Z` in your `datefmt` you want that to appear AFTER the msecs, not before.

Comment: And also if you are using a 12 hour clock which has `AM` or `PM`

Comment: @wim it's a workaround, but use UTC rather than local time by doing `logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime` then you don't need to use `%z` or `%Z`.

Alternatively you could probably change the `default_msec_format` attribute of your `logging.Formatter` object to %s,%03d%z or %s,%03d%Z

Comment: @wim as a follow up to my previous comment (couldn't edit anymore...), here is what I've done:

`from time import gmtime`
-
`# Use UTC rather than local date/time`
-
`logging.Formatter.converter = gmtime`
-
`logging.basicConfig(datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', format='%(name)s | %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ | %(message)s', level=log_level)`

Comment: @Mark You can't embed the time zone in `default_msec_format` (as of Python 3.7) because only the time and milliseconds are substituted in. From the `logging` source: `self.default_msec_format % (t, record.msecs)`

Comment: Is there a way to get make the , -> . ?  With the given format:

Comment: With the exact given format, I  still get a 2020-04-07 13:55:57,902, instead of ...57.902.'  Have I missed something? This is  with Python 3.7.3 on a RPi, logging.__version__ returns 0.5.12

Comment: With Python 3.7.6 and logging 0.5.1.2 I had to use the following (largely the same but a positional argument for the format, not `fmt=`): `formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d, %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 95):

**Please note [Craig McDaniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7517430/190597) is preferable, unless you need support for all ISO 8601 format codes.**

---

logging.Formatter's `formatTime` method looks like this:

```
def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    ct = self.converter(record.created)
    if datefmt:
        s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
    else:
        t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ct)
        s = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
    return s
```

Notice the comma in `"%s,%03d"`. This can not be fixed by specifying a `datefmt` because `ct` is a `time.struct_time` and these objects do not record milliseconds.

If we change the definition of `ct` to make it a `datetime` object instead of a `struct_time`, then (at least with modern versions of Python) we can call `ct.strftime` and then we can use `%f` to format microseconds:

```
import logging
import datetime as dt

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = ct.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            t = ct.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            s = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(console)

formatter = MyFormatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S.%f')
console.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.debug('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')
# 2011-06-09,07:12:36.553554 Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
```

---

Or, to get milliseconds, change the comma to a decimal point, and omit the `datefmt` argument:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = ct.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            t = ct.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            s = "%s.%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s

...
formatter = MyFormatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
...
logger.debug('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')
# 2011-06-09 08:14:38.343 Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
```

Comment: so %f would actually give microseconds, not milliseconds, right?

Comment: @Jonathan: oops, you are right, `%f` gives microseconds. I suppose the easiest way to get milliseconds is to change the comma to a decimal point (see edit above).

Comment: I actually think this is the best answer due to the fact that it gets you right back to being able to use STANDARD formatting options.  I actually wanted microseconds, and this was the only option that could do it!

Answer (score 69):

Adding msecs was the better option, Thanks.
Here is my amendment using this with Python 3.5.3 in Blender

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s:\t%(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info("Logging Info")
log.debug("Logging Debug")
```

Comment: By far the simplest and cleanest option. Not sure why you're getting the logger when you can just call logging.info(msg) etc, but the format is exactly what I was looking for. 
Anyone else looking for all the usable attributes can look here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Comment: Hmmm interesting point, thanks for comment it is food for thought for sure. Ya I probably just added it as a lesson in what's going on there too, and to make sure it's there and because I've asked multiple things so it doesn't need multiple calls to parent (via '.') to fetch it. If you called .info or .debug again I would maybe save those directly again as you suggest to save a reference look up cycle. [let info = logging.info]

Comment: @naphier, you are getting the logger instead of 'just' calling `logging.info(msg)` because you  usually want to exploit Python's logger name hierarchy. (such as setting different verbosity levels for certain packages or relying on `%(levelname)` yielding useful values). See also e.g. `python3 -c 'import logging; logging.basicConfig(); logging.warning("foo"); logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("bar")'`.

Answer (score 32):

The simplest way I found was to override default_msec_format:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s')
formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But this didn't work for me in Python 2.7. It may only work in Python 3.x for some value of x.

Comment: @nealmcb this isn't available until Python 3.3 per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime)

Comment: Very simple indeed! Unfortunately it only works when using the default time format (i.e. `datefmt=None`). When using a different date format (e.g. when you want to print time with milliseconds but without the data) this solution is not applicable.

Comment: if handler is not used, `logging.Formatter.default_msec_format='%s.%03d'`

Answer (score 13):

I figured out a two-liner to get the Python logging module to output timestamps in RFC 3339 (ISO 1801 compliant) format, with both properly formatted milliseconds and timezone *and* without external dependencies:

```
import datetime
import logging

# Output timestamp, as the default format string does not include it
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s: level=%(levelname)s module=%(module)s msg=%(message)s")

# Produce RFC 3339 timestamps
logging.Formatter.formatTime = (lambda self, record, datefmt=None: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created, datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat())
```

Example:

```
>>> logging.getLogger().error("Hello, world!")
2021-06-03T13:20:49.417084+02:00: level=ERROR module=<stdin> msg=Hello, world!
```

Alternatively, that last line could be written out as follows:

```
def formatTime_RFC3339(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return (
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created, datetime.timezone.utc)
        .astimezone()
        .isoformat()
    )

logging.Formatter.formatTime = formatTime_RFC3339
```

That method could also be used on specific formatter instances, rather than overriding at the class level, in which case you will need to remove `self` from the method signature.

Comment: What worked for me with Python 3.11: def formatTime_RFC3339(record, datefmt=None): return ( datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created) .astimezone() .isoformat(timespec="milliseconds") )

Answer (score 9):

Many outdated, over-complicated and weird answers here. The reason is that the documentation is inadequate and the simple solution is to just use `basicConfig()` and set it as follows:

```py
logging.basicConfig(datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', format='{asctime}.{msecs:0<3.0f} {name} {threadName} {levelname}: {message}', style='{')
```

The trick here was that you **have to also set the `datefmt`** argument, as the *default* messes it up and is **not** what is (currently) shown in the [how-to python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). So rather look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

---

An alternative and possibly cleaner way, would have been to override the `default_msec_format` variable with:

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s')
formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'
```

However, that **did not work** for unknown reasons.

<sub>PS. I am using Python 3.8.</sub>

Comment: Not sure that either of your solutions works.

Comment: @mikerodent Like I said, the first one I used and worked for me, the seconds was found in documentation and did not work. So if you're "not sure", what are you actually saying?

Comment: Doesn't print timezone, so it's not ISO8601 I'm afraid, but it works if you only need the milliseconds

Comment: @BoscoDomingo You can adjust the `datefmt` string to whatever you want/need to also include TZ in ISO-8601 time format.

Comment: why adding miliseconds does not work as part of datefmt string?

Answer (score 5):

A simple expansion that doesn't require the `datetime` module and isn't handicapped like some other solutions is to use simple string replacement like so:

```
import logging
import time

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            if "%F" in datefmt:
                msec = "%03d" % record.msecs
                datefmt = datefmt.replace("%F", msec)
            s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
        else:
            t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ct)
            s = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s
```

This way a date format can be written however you want, even allowing for region differences, by using `%F` for milliseconds. For example:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
log.addHandler(sh)

fm = MyFormatter(fmt='%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s',datefmt='%H:%M:%S.%F')
sh.setFormatter(fm)

log.info("Foo, Bar, Baz")
# 03:26:33.757-INFO-Foo, Bar, Baz
```

Answer (score 4):

After instantiating a `Formatter` I usually set `formatter.converter = gmtime`. So in order for @unutbu's answer to work in this case you'll need:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
        else:
            t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ct)
            s = "%s.%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow) or if you don't mind using arrow. You can substitute python's time formatting for arrow's one.

```
import logging

from arrow.arrow import Arrow


class ArrowTimeFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        arrow_time = Arrow.fromtimestamp(record.created)

        if datefmt:
            arrow_time = arrow_time.format(datefmt)

        return str(arrow_time)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

default_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
default_handler.setFormatter(ArrowTimeFormatter(
    fmt='%(asctime)s',
    datefmt='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
))

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(default_handler)
```

Now you can use all of [arrow's time formatting](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tokens) in `datefmt` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use `style='{'`, `fmt="{asctime}.{msecs:0<3.0f}"` will 0-pad your microseconds to three places for consistency.

Comment: This just tacks on the `,nnn` formatting (to `%S` part) when used in `logger.Formatter()`. So it need to be used in the `basicConfig(datefmt=..., format=..., style='{')`.

Answer (score 3):

After burning some of my precious time the below hack worked for me. I just updated my formatter in `settings.py` and added `datefmt` as `%y/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S` and appended the milliseconds to the asctime like this `{asctime}.{msecs:0<3.0f}`

E.G:

```
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[{asctime}.{msecs:0<3.0f}] {levelname} [{threadName:s}] {module} → {message}',
            'datefmt': "%y/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S",
            'style': '{',
        },
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear where you put this snippet. Please provide a more complete answer.

Comment: This is the only answer supporting the `{` formatting! What does the `0<3` part do? I see it for the first time and it's hard to google it.

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to do was set `default_msec_format` attribute before creating the formatter.

```
logging.Formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'                        # Just add this line
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

Comment: This is the best approach for or python 3.3+ since it works well with `logging.dictConfig()`. I just add the override in my "main" (entrypoint) function and it simply works. Remember that class attribute constants are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this smart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667155/datetime-with-milliseconds-or-microseconds-and-timezone-offset) for the timezone and the [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290739/python-logging-use-milliseconds-in-time-format/7517430#7517430), you can construct the millisecond and timezone with your desired format:

```
import logging
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tz = time.strftime('%z')
    logging.basicConfig(
        format=(
            "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d" + tz + " %(levelname)s "
            "%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d[%(threadName)s]: %(message)s"
        ),
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
    )
    logging.info("log example")
```

Personally, I like to keep all the logs in UTC but also have this explicitly in the log as a datetime without a timezone is meaningless in a multizone application:

```
    logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
    logging.basicConfig(
        format=(
            "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d+0000 %(levelname)s "
            "%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d[%(threadName)s]: %(message)s"
        ),
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
    )
```

Comment: Please provide an example usage + output.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is the following:

```
class MicrosecondsFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        return super(MicroSecondsFormatter, self).formatTime(record, self.datefmt.replace('%f', str(datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).microsecond).ljust(6, '0')))

logging.Formatter = MicrosecondsFormatter
```

The above adds support for "%f" in the date format, and so one can continue using the logging module as usual, for example:

```
log_format = f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
log_date_format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z'

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout,
                    format=log_format,
                    datefmt=log_date_format,
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Works fine. `super()` is enough instead of `super(MicroSecondsFormatter, self)`.

Comment: I like this format `logging.basicConfig( format="{asctime} {levelname:8} {module}:{lineno} {message}",
 datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f",
 style='{'
)`   optionally adding %z to the end of datefmt.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: Although it's not what the OP asked for, if you want to print all log timestamps as ISO8601 with milliseconds and UTC offset you can overwrite the default formatter `formatTime` like this:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime

def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')

logging.Formatter.formatTime = formatTime
```

produces logs like this

```
2024-01-15T19:23:01.371+01:00 INFO     __main__        test 1
```

---

The `%(asctime)s` is  formatted through [`logging.Formatter.formatTime(self, record)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime), the documentation states that `formatTime` will use [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)  which is not the same as [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). `time.strftime` has no way of printing milliseconds , `datetime.strftime()` on the other hand has [`%f`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). So you can't use `%f` on the `datefmt`.

If you only need to change the `,` (comma) to a `.` (dot) you have **the simple options from other answers combining `%(asctime)s`, and `%(msecs)03d`** like so (using `logging.config.dictConfig()` and a YAML file)

```
# log_config.yml
version: 1
formatters:
  default:
    format: "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s"
    datefmt: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

But that **will not work** if you need to **add the UTC offset /timezone after the milliseconds**, for example.

In order to have a more sensible timestamp formatting you can implement your own formatter that subclasses `logging.Formatter` and just override `formatTime`. For example, the following formatter will produce logs with timestamps in ISO8601 including milliseconds and UTC offset by using [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat):

```
# myformatter.py
import logging
from datetime import datetime

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
```

In the code above

- `record.created` is the [`LogRecord` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) representing the number of seconds (float) since the epoch returned by  [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)
- [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) is a class method that converts the epoch seconds to a datetime (naive)
- [`.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) converts the naive datetime to [timezone-aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) datetime in the local timezone
- [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat): converts the timezone aware datetime to a ISO8601 string.

```
# log_config.yml
version: 1
formatters:
  default:
    class: myformatter.CustomFormatter
    format: "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s"
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
    formatter: default
loggers:
  root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
```

The above configuration results in :

```
2024-01-15T18:40:42.006307+01:00 INFO     __main__        test 1
```

where `%(asctime)s` value comes from `CustomFormatter.formatTime()`

Ultimately you can replace the `logging.Formatter.formatTime` with your own implementation instead of creating a new formatter:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml
from datetime import datetime

def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')

logging.Formatter.formatTime = formatTime # no need for a custom formatter if we monkeypatch the default formatter

with open("log_config.yml", "rt") as f:
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.safe_load(f.read()))
    
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # __name__

myvar = 1
logger.info("test %s", myvar)
```

Answer (score -2):

tl;dr for folks looking here for an ISO formatted date:

instead of using something like '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%03d%z', create your own class as  @unutbu indicated. Here's one for iso date format:

```py
import logging
from time import gmtime, strftime

class ISOFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        t = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", gmtime(record.created))
        z = strftime("%z",gmtime(record.created))
        s = "%s.%03d%s" % (t, record.msecs,z)        
        return s

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(console)

formatter = ISOFormatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(module)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.debug('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')
#2020-10-23T17:25:48.310-0800 - <stdin> - DEBUG - Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
```

Comment: `%03d` prints the date, not milliseconds.

Comment: %03d is (was, see below) a string format modifier in this context for the milliseconds rather than a dateformat component as noted here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime

However this is mute, because this modifier apparently no longer works after 3.7 according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290739/python-logging-use-milliseconds-in-time-format/62477924?noredirect=1#comment100680659_7517430

Comment: updated the answer to be currently accurate using @unutbu 's starting point

Answer (score -4):

As of now the following works perfectly with python 3 .

```
         logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                     format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                     datefmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%03d',
                     filename=self.log_filepath,
                     filemode='w')
```

gives the following output

> 2020/01/11 18:51:19.011 INFO

Comment: This does not work. %d is printing the date. In your example the date is printed with a 0 padded in front of it.