# setting locale in Python for logging

Tags: python, logging, locale

I'm trying to use the Python logging framework. It works well except for one thing.

This sample code:

```
import logging

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('test')
```

produces this output:

```
2014-03-18 11:23:43,082 test
```

Note the comma rather than "." separating seconds from milliseconds. We are in the USA and there should be a setting somewhere which controls this.

What can I set so that the default locale info uses a period "." for a decimal separator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python logging: use milliseconds in time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290739/python-logging-use-milliseconds-in-time-format)

Comment: d'oh! it's a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The milliseconds are not part of the locale - you can't specify them using e.g. `strftime`. Hence the `,nnn` with the milliseconds is tacked on explicitly as per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).

**Update:** Although the standard allows for a dot or a comma, it implies that a comma is preferred. Currently, logging doesn't allow this to be configurable, so if you need this, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7517430/118903) in the duplicate question.

Comment: thanks for the reference but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times says "A decimal mark, either a comma or a dot (without any preference as stated in resolution 10 of the 22nd General Conference CGPM in 2003,[12] but with a preference for a comma according to ISO 8601:2004)[13] is used as a separator between the time element and its fraction".

Comment: The standard allows either a comma or a dot. Python documentation for basicConfig doesn't seem to say which.

Answer (score 4):

The following code snippet, after the `logging.basicConfig()` call, works for me in Python 3.4:

```
for h in logging.getLogger().handlers:
    h.formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at basicConfig:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

instead of : or - in my code, you can use any character if you wish.

Output:

```
2014-03-19 00:48:22 test
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can explicitly set whatever date format I want, but that's not what I asked. I want to know how to influence the `%(asctime)` locale.