# How to use millisecons in python logging, but using UTC as time?

Tags: python, logging

There are questions related on using milliseconds in python logging, there are questions related on how to use UTC, but I cannot see how to combine these two. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290739/python-logging-use-milliseconds-in-time-format) question, how can I use the UTC time for logging instead the local time?

```
def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    ct = self.converter(record.created)
    if datefmt:
        s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
    else:
        t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ct)
        s = "%s,%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` as your converter function, it'll take the local timestamp to a `datetime` that, as it has a `strftime()` method, will work just fine here.

(Unlike `time.gmtime` which returns a `struct_time` that you would have to convert again.)