# Higher precision logging module time format?

Tags: python

I am using the logging module from Python and I need to get information about the starting and ending time of different functions calls. For this, I am currently using

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s',
                              datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
```

Since the calls of a particular function do not last more than a few milliseconds, I would like to get a better precision and have more decimal digits. How can I do this?

I nice solution at: [Python logging: use milliseconds in time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290739/python-logging-use-milliseconds-in-time-format?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If you're looking for a **working example down to nano-second precision**, I have posted one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55612356/1672565). The answer below this question is not really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will update this answer because the solution wasn't good. A good answer can be found here [Python Logging Module logging timestamp to include microsecond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328300/python-logging-module-logging-timestamp-to-include-microsecond)