# Datetime with milliseconds or microseconds AND timezone offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, logging, timezone

This is the representation desired for dates:

```
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
>>> datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z(%Z)'
>>> datetime.now(tz).strftime(datefmt)
'2017-04-27 15:09:59.606921-0500(CDT)'
```

This is how it's logged (Python 3.6.0 on Linux):

```
>>> logrecord_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
>>> logging.basicConfig(format=logrecord_format, datefmt=datefmt)
>>> logging.error('ruh-roh!')
2017-04-27 15:10:35.%f-0500(CDT) ERROR ruh-roh!
```

It's not filling the microseconds properly.  I've tried changing the `logrecord_format` to a few other things, but I could not figure it out - how to configure the logger to show microseconds and timezone in the correct way to match the `strftime` output exactly?

---

***Edit***:  I could settle for milliseconds with offset, i.e. `2017-04-27 15:09:59,606-0500(CDT)`. Is that possible?  `logging` provides `%(msecs)03d` directive, but I can't seem to get the timezone offset to appear *after* the milliseconds.

Comment: [It looks like `logging` uses `time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime) rather than `datetime.datetime.strftime`, and `time.strftime` doesn't support microseconds (or milliseconds, so they use a weird hack to add those in with the default format).

Comment: If you want to do this anyway, you'd have to write your own `Formatter` subclass that implements `formatTime` differently.

Comment: But `time.strftime` does support microseconds correctly on my platform: `datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')` --> `'15:42:54.516274'`.

Comment: `time.strftime` as in the `strftime` function in the `time` module, not `datetime.time.strftime`.

Comment: They are different?  Oh.   WTF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, instead of integrating the timezone into the date format, I add it directly to the logged message format. Usually, the timezone should not change during the program execution.

```
import logging
import time

tz = time.strftime('%z')
fmt = '%(asctime)s' + tz + ' %(levelname)s %(message)s'

logging.basicConfig(format=fmt)

logging.error("This is an error message.")

# 2017-07-28 19:34:53,336+0200 ERROR This is an error message.
```

Comment: clever way to avoid subclassing - doesn't support microseconds though

Answer (score 3):

More formally than the accepted answer, and to get microseconds, you need to use `datetime` instead of `time` for the string formatting.

```
import logging
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

class TZAwareFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    A timezone-aware logging formatter.

    By default, Python's `logging` module uses the `time` module for conversion
    of timestamps to time tuples, which doesn't support %f for microsecond formatting
    """
    def __init__(self, tz, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tz = tz
        
    def converter(self, timestamp):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, self.tz)

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            s = dt.strftime(self.default_time_format)
            if self.default_msec_format:
                s = self.default_msec_format % (s, record.msecs)

        return s
```

And how to use it:

```
# Update the logging root handler to use correct Formatter
logging.basicConfig()
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_handler = root_logger.handlers[0]

root_handler.setFormatter(
    TZAwareFormatter(
        tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central'),
        fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z (%Z)'
    )
)
logging.error('uh-oh!')
```