# Microsecond part lost when converting a date string to a datetime object in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have the following date string:

```
dtstr = '2010-12-19 03:44:34.778000'
```

I wanted to convert it to a datetime object, so i proceeded as follows:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

dtstr = '2010-12-19 03:44:34.778000'
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(dtstr,format)))
```

But this returned : `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 3, 44, 34)` instead of `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 3, 44, 34,778000)`

Why did the microsecond part get omitted ?. How can i get `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 3, 44, 34,778000)`  ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

dtstr = '2010-12-19 03:44:34.778000'
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
a = datetime.strptime(dtstr,format)
print a.microsecond
```

`time` handles seconds since the Unix epoch, so using `time` loses the microseconds. Use `datetime.strptime` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The `time.struct_time` object returned by `time.strptime` does not store milliseconds:

```
In [116]: time.strptime(dtstr,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f",)
Out[116]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=3, tm_min=44, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=353, tm_isdst=-1)
```

But the datetime object returned by `dt.datetime.strptime` does store milliseconds:

```
In [117]: import datetime as dt

In [118]: dt.datetime.strptime(dtstr,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
Out[118]: datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 3, 44, 34, 778000)
```