# appengine import_transform two function at the same time: truncate & export_date_time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I have this datetime `2011-07-02 03:03:32.793`

To deal with the millisecond issue with python 2.5 version(mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python)), I try to  truncate it & convert it date time as:

```
import_transform: 'lambda x: x[:18]'
import_transform: transform.import_date_time('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

How can I write these two import_transform in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by writing a lambda function that does both together:

```
import-transform: lambda x: transform.import_date_time('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')(x[:18])
```

Note the chained function calls - `transform.import_date_time` returns a function, which you're then calling.