# Python convert string to datetime for comparison to datetime object

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime

I have a string `lfile` with a datetime in it (`type(lfile)` gives `<type 'str'>`) and a Python datetime object `wfile`. Here is the code:

```
import os, datetime
lfile = '2005-08-22_11:05:45.000000000'
time_w = os.path.getmtime('{}\\{}.py' .format('C:\Temp_Readouts\RtFyar','TempReads.csv'))
wfile = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_w)
```

`wfile` contains this `2006-11-30 19:08:06.531328` and `repr(wfile)` gives:

```
datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 30, 19, 8, 6, 531328)
```

**Problem:**

I need to:

1. convert `lfile` into a Python datetime object
2. compare `lfile` to `wfile` and determine which datetime is more recent

For 1.:

I am only able to get a partial solution using `strptime` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python). Here is what I tried:

```
lfile = datetime.datetime.strptime(linx_file_dtime, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
```

The output is:

```
`ValueError: unconverted data remains: .000`
```

*Question 1*

It seems that `strptime()` [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/format-nanoseconds-in-python) handle the nano seconds. How do I tell `strptime()` to ignore the last 3 zeros?

For 2.:

When I use `type(wfile)` I get `<type 'datetime.datetime'>`. If both `wfile` and `lfile` are Python datetime objects (i.e. if step 1. is successful), then would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates) work?:

```
if wtime < ltime:
    print 'Linux file created after Windows file'
else:
    print 'Windows file created after Linux file'
```

*Question 2*

Or is there some other way in which Python can compare datetime objects to determine which of the two occurred after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

Python handles microseconds, not nano seconds.  You can strip the last three characters of the time to convert it to microseconds and then add `.%f` to the end:

```
lfile = datetime.datetime.strptime(linx_file_dtime[:-3], '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

**Question 2**

Yes, comparison works:

```
if wtime < ltime:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, `strptime()` does not handle nanoseconds. The accepted answer in the question that you linked to offers an option: strip off the last 3 digits and then parse with `.%f` appended to the format string.

Another option is to use `dateutil.parser.parse()`:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('2005-08-22_11:05:45.123456789', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2005, 8, 22, 11, 5, 45, 123456)
```

`fuzzy=True` is required to overlook the unsupported underscore between date and time components. Because `datetime` objects do not support nanoseconds, the last 3 digits vanish, leaving microsecond accuracy.

Comment: Ha! Apologies for missing that. Seems the question might already have been answered in that earlier link I posted. Thanks for your answer as well!