# Search text file for a time range - python

Tags: python-2.7

I am playing around with python and I am trying to figure out a way to search a text file for a specific word within a time range. The file has time stamps, however since the file is a text file everything is a string.

Text file contains the below:

```
17:14:26.442 words words words words words

17:15:32.533 words words words words words

17:16:26.442 words words words words words

17:17:32.533 words words words words words

17:18:26.442 words words words words words

17:19:32.533 words words words words words

17:20:26.442 words words words words words

17:21:32.533 words words words words words
```

What I want to do is search for a word in a time frame and get back only that line that has word between 17:17:32.533 and 17:20:26.442. However, since its a text document and everything is a string I cannot use the range option. Does anyone have some suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Is `17:17:32.533` a timestamp? What does it denote?

Comment: do you have to do it only once per file, or many times? and do you want to perform a word only search or a substring search?

Comment: If you have a lot of times to check against the file, you should sort the data by time and then use bisect to get log n lookups

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: Exactly what I was heading to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module to parse and convert the timestamp strings to `datetime` object and then you can use the comparison in order to check only the lines that fall in that time range.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

start = dt.strptime('17:17:32.533','%H:%M:%S.%f')
end = dt.strptime('17:20:26.442','%H:%M:%S.%f')
word_to_search = 'word'
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ts=dt.strptime(line.split()[0],'%H:%M:%S.%f')
        if ts>start and ts<end:
            if word_to_search in line:
                print line
```

Comment: naïve question: why not using `time.strptime` ?

Comment: I think it does not work as I read the first answer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python

Comment: Actually it might just work, the `struct_time` may not contain microseconds but if there are no duplicate timestamps (removing milliseconds) then it will work fine.

Comment: Ok, better safe than sorry, I'll use `datetime` from now on. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamps are exactly in the format you describe (HH:MM:SS.sss), then you can compare directly:

```py
start = '17:17:32.533'
end = '17:20:26.442'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:12] >= start and line[:12] <= end:
            print(line)
```

If this doesn't work, because e.g. 01:01:01.000 is outputted as 1:1:1.0, you have to parse the timestamp first. For example:

```py
import datetime
start = datetime.time(17, 17, 32, 533)
end = datetime.time(17, 20, 26, 442)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        timestamp, words = line.split(None, 1)
        time = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
        if time >= start and time <= end:
            print(words)
```

Comment: split takes no keyword args, you want  `line.split(None,1)`

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, wrong python version. In Python3 it does.

Comment: Thanks TIm Fuchs, I will test and play around with it some and post here what I find. I appreciate your detailed and quick response! I'm on python Version 2.7