# How to convert all possible types of datetime formats using python module

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert all possible types of datetime formats to '`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`' without error.

For example, '`2016-01-21 12:36:59.124`' or '`2016-Jan-12 21:36:12' or '16-January-23 23:59:32.1`should be converted to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format without raising any error?

Comment: Is this for converting older dates into your format, or is it to get the datetime is a specific format?

Comment: "All possible types" is impossible. Would "05-04-2016 12:00:00" be the fourth of May (US) or the fifth or April (Europe) ?

Comment: I mean to avoid errors such as 'ValueError: unconverted data remains: .124'

Answer (score 3):

```
from dateutil import parser

print parser.parse('2016-01-21 12:36:59.124')
print parser.parse('2016-Jan-12 21:36:12')
print parser.parse('16-January-23 23:59:32.1')
```

Output:

```
2016-01-21 12:36:59.124000
2016-01-12 21:36:12
2023-01-16 23:59:32.100000
```

Comment: I need help to convert to  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' not to parse and check if date or not

Comment: Do you want to add 2 minutes to the minutes and have 4 seconds when it's 124 seconds?

Comment: `'2016-Jan-12 21:36:124'` No. It's seconds in this case. Which will throw error.

Comment: Its milliseconds only
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python
but I dont want the solution in the link

Comment: `Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds`

Comment: In one example it's in milliseconds. In other example it's in seconds. Please read the strings you have mentioned in the question closely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130710/discussion-between-mohammad-yusuf-ghazi-and-user2225190).

Answer (score 0):

using strftime() and strptime() functions you would be able to convert them without issues.

Comment: We are not sure of the input from end user, he can give any format