# Converting string with decimals into datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time

This question is very similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime), but my data is on the form:

```
'13-04-2018 14:06:26.866'
'13-04-2018 14:06:27.131'
'13-04-2018 14:06:27.404'
'13-04-2018 14:06:27.674'
...
```

i.e. the seconds are given as decimals. My reading of the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) suggests that it doesn't support this format, so I am not sure how to best proceed.

Comment: The question you linked in your question described perfectly the two parameters you need to convert your strings to time.

Comment: @chrisz I don't see it. What parameters are used to read seconds as floats?

Comment: @TokeFaurby You use `%S` for the integer part of the seconds and `%f` for the fractional part of the seconds.  There is no format specifier for "seconds with fractions" or "seconds as floats".

Comment: @Alfe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python better dupe target?

Comment: @chrisz Yup, way better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need

- `.%f == Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = '13-04-2018 14:06:26.866'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-04-13 14:06:26.866000
```

Comment: Ahh, you are right. The 'padded on the left' confused me, but it works