# correct parsing for a str date time in ddmmyyyy:HH:MM:SS.xxx format

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I have the following datetime values in dask dataframe saved as string dates:

```
ddf = dd.DataFrame({'date': ['15JAN1955:13:15:27.369', NaN,'25DEC1990:23:18:17.200', '06MAY1962:02:55:27.360', NaN, '20SEP1975:12:02:26.357']}
```

I used `ddf['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f"), meta=datetime)` but I get a `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be a str, not float` error.

I am following the way dates were parsed from the book: Data Science with python and dask.

Is the `.%f` expecting a float? Or maybe it has something to do with `NaN` values?

Comment: `NaN` is, indeed, a `float` value, and would appear to be the source of the error. `%f` has nothing in particular to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`%f`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) that [parses any decimal fraction of seconds with up to 6 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python)

Also `20SEPT1975` should be `20SEP1975` (no `T` in month)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['15JAN1955:13:15:27.369', np.nan,
                            '25DEC1990:23:18:17.200', np.nan,
                            '06MAY1962:02:55:27.360', '20SEP1975:12:02:26.357']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(df)
```

```
                     date
0 1955-01-15 13:15:27.369
1                     NaT
2 1990-12-25 23:18:17.200
3                     NaT
4 1962-05-06 02:55:27.360
5 1975-09-20 12:02:26.357
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought your suggestion should work but I forgot to mention in the original post that the dates were string datatype. When I used the %f, I got a Typerror:. I think the .%f is expecting a float.

Comment: You haven't show how you are using `strptime`. `%f` doesn't expect a float any more than any of the other numerical placeholders do.

Comment: Sorry, original post updated with the whole line of strptime used

Comment: @DennisDavid my solution with `pd.to_datetime` handles `NaN` and changes it to `NaT` (not a time), so that seems ok ?

Comment: The @azro, Initially when I tried it, it says the length of the ddf does not match the index, but maybe I was too tired already, I thought or debugging and optimizing my lines of codes and hopefully I get this to work.

Comment: @azro, update, It actually converted the dates using your method, but the issue now is assigning the column ack to the source dask df. That is when I get a valueerror saying the length of values does not match the length of index. Thank you